# Viewstate Disabled - Dropdown box not returning values

Tags: asp.net, viewstate

In an effort to speed up my site, I am trying to disable the viewstate as I don't think I am using it everywhere. I have a master page setup with user controls loaded (using LoadControl) in default.aspx. My typical page setup would be:

`Main.master -> Default.aspx -> ControlWrapper.ascx -> MyControl.ascx`

I have put EnableViewState="false" in my Default.aspx page. Now when I try and read a value from a `DropDownList in MyControl.ascx` it comes back blank when the form is posted. First all, why is this? I thought I should still be able to read the value from the drop down list?

I then tried enabling the ViewState on that control and it didn't work.

I also tried enabling the viewstate on the `Page_Init` event of `MyControl.ascx` using `Page.EnableViewState = True;` but that didn't help either.

I guess I am misunderstanding the viewstate somewhat, can someone point me in the right direction please?

p.s I don't know if this information is relevant but I am adding the contents of the DropDownList dynamically in the Page_Load event. (Thinking about it, could this be the issues - Will test this now).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will assume you're using .NET 4. View State is the method that the ASP.NET page framework uses to preserve page and control values between round trips.

The reason it didn't work for you when View State was turned off is because that control was rendered again when you performed a PostBack to the server, meaning you lost your selected value.

The reason it didn't work for you when View State was off for the page, but on for the control is because in order for that to work, the [following conditions must be met](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.enableviewstate.aspx):

- The EnableViewState property for the page is set to true.
- The EnableViewState property for the control is set to true.
- The ViewStateMode property for the control is set to Enabled or inherits the Enabled setting.

[ASP .NET View State Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386448.aspx)

Comment: Ok, I am using .NET 2.0 (sorry forgot to say in OP), does that make any difference to any of the points?

Comment: If I remember correctly, no it shouldn't make a difference. ASP.NET 4 just gives you a few more options for managing your ViewState. You're still going to need it turned on for your page and your control if you want to be able to retrieve the selected value of your drop down list. If I were you, I'd turn it on by default, and the selectively turn it off where it makes sense. If you have performance problems, there are other methods you can employ, such as saving ViewState to a database.

Comment: How would saving it to a database work? Can you reccommend any articles for this?

Answer (score 4):

With viewstate turned off, the values you are loading in Page_Load are no longer in the list when you post back (until you reload them obviously). If you want to work without viewstate, you will need to set the selected item from the value in Request.Form.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    ddlItems.Items.Add(new ListItem("test1", "test1"));
    ddlItems.Items.Add(new ListItem("test2", "test2"));
    ddlItems.Items.Add(new ListItem("test3", "test3"));

    if (Page.IsPostBack)
        ddlItems.SelectedValue = Request.Form["ddlItems"];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When you've set ViewState to false the dropdown needs to get populated before page load - which means you probably should do it at page init. Something like this:

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    ddlItems.Items.Add(new ListItem("test1", "test1"));
    ddlItems.Items.Add(new ListItem("test2", "test2"));
    ddlItems.Items.Add(new ListItem("test3", "test3"));
}
```

Then you should be able to read the value at load:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    someTextBox = ddlItems.SelectedValue;
}
```

**A bit of background**:

On this page: [Microsofts page cycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

At the image with the page cycle there is the methods "ProcessPostData" and "LoadPostData" firing in between Init and Load. The post data for the drop down contains the selected value - but not the possible values, so when it loads the post data it is essential that the possible values are already there (or it won't be able to set the selected value). Also before the post data has been loaded the selected value has not been set.

If viewstate is enabled it saves and retrieves the possible values in between postbacks.

Answer (score 0):

When you did `EnableViewState = false;` on a page then you should not expect `DropdownList.SelectedValue` after postback.

It will be good if you Enable/Disable `ViewState` on particular controls rather than disabling whole view state by specifying it on page directive.

Comment: I agree this would be better but I have hundreds of control, most of which don't need it enabled. That is why I wanted to disable and enable for what I need it for.